# Boost undefined symbol when building .so library with CMake

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

I'm building a shared library (.so) on Linux with CMake which uses Boost 1.75.0.

In CMakeLists.txt, Boost is added the following way:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system chrono filesystem date_time log iostreams program_options)
```

and added to the target:

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

CMake finds Boost, so no problem here.

Boost is linked as a static library. When I list the linked object files, I get the correct libraries:

```
-- LIB_FILES: ...;/path/to/boost/debug/lib/libboost_filesystem.a;...
```

The library compiles and links without error.

However, when I use a simple function of the library, I get the following error:

```
undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
```

This symbol is indeed undefined in the library:

```
$ nm -g libmytarget.so | grep _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
                 U _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
```

The demangled name is `boost::filesystem::filesystem_error::what() const`, which is defined in `boost/filesystem/exception.hpp` as

```
namespace boost
{
  namespace filesystem
  {
    class BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL filesystem_error : public std::exception
    {
    public:
      virtual const char * what() const throw();
...
```

Note that my code does **not** call this method.

The symbol is defined in `libboost_filesystem.a`, which is used by the linker, as a symbol in the text (code) section:

```
$ nm -g /path/to/boost/debug/lib/libboost_filesystem.a | grep _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
00000000000003fa T _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
```

**My question**:

I don't understand how it is possible that this symbol is undefined in the compiled library, when it is present in the statically linked lib (file `libboost_filesystem.a`), which is recognized and used by the linker.

Comment: Not sure what your compiler flags are like, but this sounds a lot like an issue I've seen where -flto and -fdevirtualize don't play nicely together with gcc pre 9.0.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua I'm using g++ 10.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` in CMake solved the problem:

```
set_target_properties(mytarget PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
```

Now, the symbol is properly linked:

```
$ nm -g libmytarget.so | grep filesystem_error4what
00000000001cfe22 T _ZNK5boost10filesystem16filesystem_error4whatEv
```

But I still don't know what's going on behind the scenes and why this error pops up in the first place.